# Ice Cream Sandwich broke setError() for EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I use setError() on a EditText for validation. It was working fine prior to upgrading to ICS, but now the error box is empty. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this on my Nexus S running Android 4.0.3.

Here's how I made it work.

1. Create a theme with:

   ```
   <style name="MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/primary_text_light
        </item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Apply `MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar` theme to my application / activity  from manifest.

   ```
       <application
            android:name=".MyApp"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
       >
   ```

Comment: I fixed it as well, changing the theme for a specific activity.

Answer (score 2):

Might it be connected to this reported bug?

[Issue 22920:   EditText: setError not readable when using Light Theme](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22920&q=setError&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Don't know how to fix or get around it though. =(

Comment: Thats probably the same issue. I guess I'd just raise my targetSDK and use a different theme.